# How can I publish one of my devices as DNS server when using IPv6?

Tags: router, dns, ipv6, pihole

I run Pi hole, and I have a TP link router (Archer C6) with IPv6 capabilities.

My ISP seams to supports this type of connection via "dynamic IP (SLAAC/DHCPv6)".
I think I'm encountering kind of chicken and egg situation:

- On one hand I need to know my Pi hole's IPv6 and write it as primary and secondary DNS address.
- On the other hand (with prefix delegation), my router can only know its prefix only after it gets an address from my ISP (with other DNS address like Cloudflare).

When I use the cloudflare DNS address, I get an IPv6 address and I want to change it to my Pi hole's address, my router releases it's IPv6 address and apparently tries again with the-non-relevant-anymore Pi hole's address.

Another thing, I can't use addresses like `fe80::4bd2:67c1:9247:3c91/64` (without the `/64` postfix), the router says that it's not a valid DNS address.

What can I do? is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: IIRC your Pi-Hole device could use its own DHCPv6 service and only announce DNS (not addresses).

Comment: @DanielB how so?in order to turn on this feature I need to turn on its IPv4 DHCP… if not, its DHCPv6s checkbox is in read only state. And still, if it would be possible, the address can be changed after so and so hours, doesn’t it? So I will have to track it manually and change it in my router…

Comment: Dunno, I'm not using Pi-Hole myself, sorry. There's no technical requirement to run a DHCPv4 server for DHCPv6. Because the DHCPv6 server also gets up-to-date IPv6 information using Router Advertisements, manual changes should not be necessary.

Comment: Ask your ISP to supply you a static IPv6 subnet. That should also mean the WAN IPv6 address will also be static. There is no reason why they cannot do that.

Comment: I understand, but it seems that this is the implementation (at least GUI wise) of the DHCP setting in the  Hole settings

Comment: @Bib but let’s say I’ll get a IPv6 prefix, I don’t have the ability to reserve an IPv6 address in my router, or did you mean something else?

Comment: You are dealing with 2 separate issues, first, the WAN address, and second, internal to your network. You need to take a step at a time.

Comment: @Bib I've asked my ISP and they said that don't support static IPv6 address so... is there any other option or all is lost?

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is find another ISP.